# How do you print a list of values in one column?

Tags: list, printing, output

I have calculated a list of values from an equation and I want to print all 140 of the output values in a single column, so that I can convert it to a txt document with one column of data. When I say `print(values)`, it prints the output in multiple columns.

For example:

```
N = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(N)
```

This is the result: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I want these values in a single column.

Comment: welcome to stack-overflow, please read [MCVE], please add your code trials with what language bindings

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[1,2,3,4] #let this be the list
for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i],"/n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = [1,2,3,4,5] #your list here
for i in range(0,len(N)):
    print(N[i],"\n")
```

Just rmb to use backslash in "\n" to go to next line instead of "/n".

[image]